# angular lazy load module in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

Can I lazy load module in lazy loaded module?
I have such module for 'publications' route, but it loads too much functionality for editing this publication while user maybe don`t have permissions for this. So I try to optimize it somehow, because I have similar components with 'edit/add' depending on permissions.
If you have suggestions for optimizing by permissions somehow, will be glad.

UPDATED
Yes, you can. Just import other module for route inside lazy loaded module

Comment: I think using stacked LazyLoaded Modules should work out of the box. You just need to implement them as normal LazyLoaded Modules. But It's a longe time ago when I used it so I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

`FpgTimeComponent` is not a part of the files of the lazy module that will be loaded, so you can't do that. Think about it, you are trying to import a component in the lazy module that the module knows nothing about since it isn't defined in that module, and it isn't defined in any other module you have imported in the `LazyModule`. So where is it going to get the component from?

Add `FpgTimeComponent` to a `SharedModule` and import the `SharedModule` in your `LazyModule`, or move the `FpgTimeComponent` to your `LazyModule`. Once you do one of those, it should work then.

This is a better approach anyways, because I can guarantee as you keep developing you will keep running into the same error with other components/other lazy modules. If you are using the components in multiple places, then they should live in a `SharedModule` as [Angular best practices defines](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules), and that `SharedModule` should be imported in all your lazy modules.

Here is an example.

**SharedModule:**

```
import { FpgTimeComponent } from './some/path';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FpgTimeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FpgTimeComponent
    ]
})
```

**LazyModule:**

```
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { LazyComponent }   from './lazy.component';
import { routing } from './lazy.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing,
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        LazyComponent
    ]
})
```